# Question about restricted user profiles on 4.4.3 KitKat tablet

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, settings, multi-user, restricted-profiles

I realize that 4.4.3 is a very old version at this point so let me explain my situation for context. I work as IT in a small trucking company, we are a client of another company called PeopleNet who provides us with units to track our trucks, take driver logs, provide GPS, etc. Recently we purchased some of their MS5 PeopleNet Connected Android tablet units from them, along with their application we also wanted drivers to use certain applications that railyards are beginning to regularly use for in-gating and out-gating loads. Obviously though, we don't want them to have access to much beyond those.

PeopleNet wants us to send the tablets back for a 3 week period and pay 12$ a month to do this for us on a tablet system that was already 900$, which is ridiculous. Setting up a restricted user profile has pretty much provided everything minus one exception, the PeopleNet application (called PMobile) is not listed at under the applications for the restricted user at all.

I was wondering if someone with much more knowledge of Android could tell me, is this application not showing because I know at version 4.4.3 that restricted user profiles were a fairly new feature (It is also impossible for me to update the tablet past this version.)? This application was also NOT installed through the Play Store, but through a USB stick, could that be the issue? The application also has a plethora of permissions it requires, does this make it unusable in a restricted user profile at all?

If anyone could help me understand or even get the app to show so I can turn it on/off for the restricted user profile I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.